# Simple math with Python and Flask

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am fairly new to Flask, and am working on a simple website to do calculations (noting too difficult, just simple additions, division). I am currently using an Flask-WTF and creating a form that uses IntegerField's to collect information. Here is my forms.py:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import IntegerField, SubmitField, validators, ValidationError

class investment(Form):
    A = IntegerField("Enter value A: ")
    B = IntegerField("Enter value B: ")
    submit = SubmitField("Calculate")
```

Here is my routes.py:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = investment()

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        return A + B

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

Anyone know how I can add A and B together after the user has filled out the form and hit submit? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was so focused on getting the code up that I completely forgot. I want to know how to add values A and B

Comment: You should include your `home.html` template, you should include a description or the evidence of the problem you're actually having, and you should probably be looking to return the result A+B in a new page, not as some number.

Answer (score 3):

You should give [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/wtforms/) more time -

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = investment(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate(): 
        sumtn = form.A.data + form.B.data
        # Do what you want with sum

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name it shadows the bif.

Comment: Ok, I tried this, but I keep on getting: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: ok the traceback is too long to paste her, but I managed to create a text document in dropbox: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlxjnd39xxucx3c/traceback.rtf

Comment: @nawawaz use pastebin.com from next time. And the error you're facing now is for a completely different reason. Have you overwritten any variable named `app` somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure, where should I be looking? I can share my files forms, routes and home.py files if it would help.

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple problems with your code, but an obvious problem is

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = investment()

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        return A + B # <--- where do A and B come from? They're never defined!

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

I am not sure how wtforms/flask-wtf expects you to get to them for sure, but I think it's something like

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = investment(request.POST)
        return form.A + form.B

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = investment()
        return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

You'll have to check out the documentation to be sure

- https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/